# Posting YouTube video to Facebook

Tags: facebook, youtube

If a YouTube video is posted on Facebook, do the views still count on YouTube every time the video is accessed through Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube counts views regardless of what site the video is embedded in.

One of the analytic reports they offer is [Playback Locations](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714546?hl=en&ref_topic=3029003) which details which includes the following metric (amongst others)

> Embedded players on other websites: This shows how many people viewed your video when it was embedded on another website, like a blog. Click on the link to drill down to a breakdown of views across the various sites that have embedded your video.